# What happen to drivers when changing linux kernel in ubuntu?

Tags: kernel, multiple-monitors, cuda

My question is very large, although what led to it what very specific, and I have related additional questions. So here is the full story.

###### Intro

I'm currently running a Ubuntu 20.04 with two screens on a classic tower with a Nvidia graphic card (I think spec of the computer are irrelevant here, so I'll skip that). One of the screens is plug to VGA, the other one on a DisplayPort. Everything was fine until I try some CUDA and install the CUDA Toolkit 11.7.

###### Problem

At that point, the VGA screen was the only one recognized by the computer, the other one being not recognized, not even detected. If I unplugged the VGA and reboot, the DisplayPort was used but the screen resolution was terribly off. I tried to make both of them displaying something, looking into nvidia doc and all user problems (I know there are many problems between Nvidia and Ubuntu, been there before) but nothing worked. So I uninstalled (purge) the toolkit, drivers and stuff. Still didn't worked. Then I realized the installation has changed my kernel from 5.13-... to 5.15... (which is weird, because CUDA doc says that 5.13.0-30 at least is fine. Anyway).

So I changed the kernel back to 5.13... (5.13.0-51.58, if you ask), and tadaa, both screens are working just fine.

###### Question (s)

To me, it is a driver issue, and I don't understand why a kernel change might to the trick.

So here's the questions

- Why ? Why is that ? (I don't know if it counts as a real question)
- Can it be a bug in the kernel ? (even if I doubt that)
- Did I forget to purge some faulty drivers working with 5.15.. but not with 5.13.. and the update was made when downgrading kernel ?
- I'm seeing that now, the 'nouveau' driver is in use (via `lspci`) and I don't recall seeing it with 5.15.. . Would it have been possible to force it's use with kernel 5.15.. ? (The answer is yes, the question is 'how ?')

##### Edit :

Doing some tests, it appears that the package(s) provoking that bug for me is the `nvidia-gds`, which installs the linux kernel 5.15- along some other stuff. I purged all of that before changing the kernel, so I'm pretty sure it's the kernel change that made both my screens working again. I've reinstalled the cuda toolkit and it's working fine, without the GDS. I still don't know why.

Comment: Ubuntu LTS releases offer two primary kernel stacks (*I'm ignoring OEM options for simplicity here*); the GA kernel stack is the most stable & doesn't change, the HWE changes during the first ~two years of the product, recently that meant 5.13 (from 21.10) switched to 5.15 (from 22.04 LTS)...  The installer selects the kernel stack used by ISO used to install (unless `subiquity` installer ISO is used where it's changing during installation) ; if you don't want it to change - use the GA kernel stack.  Ubuntu 21.10 is reaching EOL & the 5.13 kernel is going EOL... why it upgraded

Comment: *Drivers* is a human term, technically they're kernel modules; thus changing kernel means new kernel modules are required (ie. *drivers* change). That is why the GA kernel stack is seen as the more *stable* option; why it's the default for server & some installations... Desktop users though tend to want later '*drivers*' which is why desktop systems default to the HWE stack (the original ISO though still dictates this; esp. for *flavors* of Ubuntu; Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop defaulted to HWE for all ISOs differing to prior releases or *flavors* for 20.04 & later LTS releases)

Comment: @guiverc So if I understand well, I should install kernel 5.4 generic and I shall be fine ? I have "old" ressouces and I probably won't need new drivers (btw I know they're kernel modules, it's just faster to write 'driver', but you're absolutely right), as I deal with "old" hardware, I probably don't need HWE (unless it does additional stuff I'm not aware of).

Comment: You can view https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack and other wiki pages for more details on GA/HWE/OEM kernel options (*GA/HWE available for LTS only*).  The benefit of GA is it doesn't change.. thus it's the default for server installs as is deemed more *stable* (also note *flavors* of 20.04 & 20.04.1; HWE being default for 20.04.2 & later ISOs except server)... You can have both GA & HWE on the same box; though some closed source kernel modules (aka *video drivers*) prevent this; but if using open source they'll co-exist too. In most cases GA is the more *stable*, esp. on older..

Comment: What method did you use to install the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: @mchid Fetching the .deb on their website and following the steps.

Comment: @Theragondin The same proprietary nvidia drivers are available from the official Ubuntu repositories. The only difference is that the ones from the Ubuntu repositories are designed to avoid the exact problems you're encountering. You should always use `sudo apt update` and then `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` to install the drivers.

Comment: @mchid To be exact, I added the ```nvidia-gds``` package to the installation, from the [nvidia installation guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#ubuntu-installation-common), are you saying they should change that to better fit ubuntu ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why? Why is that? (I don't know if it counts as a real question)

In general everything has to be compatible for a system with Nvidia proprietary graphics drivers and CUDA to work correctly. There are perhaps a thousand different ways to match Nvidia, CUDA and kernel packages, but only one of them is best which is to match everything.

Patching together non-matching Nvidia and CUDA packages is asking for trouble. Additionally both Nvidia proprietary graphics drivers and CUDA packages must be compatible with the Linux kernel version. Patching together non-matching Nvidia, CUDA and kernel packages is also asking for trouble. All these packages are in the default Ubuntu repositories, so if you stick with the default Ubuntu repositories all your installed packages will always be compatible with each other.

> Can it be a bug in the kernel?

This is very unlikely in this case. I see too many possibilities for accumulated chains of user errors here.

> Did I forget to purge some faulty drivers working with 5.15, but not with 5.13 and the update was made when downgrading kernel?

Look in the logs and the logs will tell you what packages were purged. In cases like this I always start by uninstalling all Nvidia packages, so that I am working from a clean slate. This is the simplest possible way to avoid introducing sources of errors from the very start.

> I'm seeing that now, the 'nouveau' driver is in use (via `lspci`) and I don't recall seeing it with 5.15. Would it have been possible to force its use with kernel 5.15? (The answer is yes, the question is 'how?')

There's absolutely no point to ever uninstalling nouveau because it's your failsafe driver if you make a mistake installing the proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers. Leave nouveau installed whatever you do. If something bad happens with the proprietary Nvidia graphics driver Ubuntu will try to boot with the nouveau driver instead.